# Swift 5 group and split array of objects based on object value

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a sorted array

```
let things = [
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value1"),
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value2"),
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value3"),
    Thing(activity: "2", name: "value4"),
    Thing(activity: "2", name: "value5"),
    Thing(activity: "3", name: "value6"),
    Thing(activity: "3", name: "value7"),
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value8"),
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value9"),
    Thing(activity: "1", name: "value10")
 ]
```

I would like to produce array of arrays splitted when the activity value changes similar to the following

```
[[Thing(activity: "1", name: "value1"),
  Thing(activity: "1", name: "value2"),
  Thing(activity: "1", name: "value3")],
 [Thing(activity: "2", name: "value4"),
  Thing(activity: "2", name: "value5")],
 [Thing(activity: "3", name: "value6"),
  Thing(activity: "3", name: "value7")],
 [Thing(activity: "1", name: "value8"),
  Thing(activity: "1", name: "value9"),
  Thing(activity: "1", name: "value10")]]
```

Comment: Use `reduce(into:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned by @matt in comments you can use collection method reduce(into:) to group your elements by checking if the activity of the  last element of the last array is equal to the current element activity, if so just append a new element to the last array, otherwise append a new array with a single element to the outer array:

```
struct Thing {
    let activity, name: String
}
```

---

```
let things: [Thing] = [
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value1"),
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value2"),
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value3"),
    .init(activity: "2", name: "value4"),
    .init(activity: "2", name: "value5"),
    .init(activity: "3", name: "value6"),
    .init(activity: "3", name: "value7"),
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value8"),
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value9"),
    .init(activity: "1", name: "value10")]
```

---

```
let grouped: [[Thing]] = things.reduce(into: []) {
    $0.last?.last?.activity == $1.activity ?
    $0[$0.index(before: $0.endIndex)].append($1) :
    $0.append([$1])
}

print(grouped)  // "[[__lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value1"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value2"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value3")], [__lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "2", name: "value4"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "2", name: "value5")], [__lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "3", name: "value6"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "3", name: "value7")], [__lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value8"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value9"), __lldb_expr_1.Thing(activity: "1", name: "value10")]]\n"
```

Comment: Worked like charm!. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A generalized solution would be:

```
extension Sequence {
    func grouped<T: Equatable>(by block: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [[Element]] {
        return try reduce(into: []) { result, element in
            if let lastElement = result.last?.last, try block(lastElement) == block(element) {
                result[result.index(before: result.endIndex)].append(element)
            } else {
                result.append([element])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let results = things.grouped { $0.activity }
```

---

A less elegant (but slightly more efficient) solution would be:

```
extension Sequence {
    func grouped<T: Equatable>(by block: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [[Element]] {
        var results: [[Element]] = []

        var lastValue: T?
        var index = results.endIndex
        for element in self {
            let value = try block(element)
            if let lastValue = lastValue, lastValue == value {
                results[index].append(element)
            } else {
                results.append([element])
                index = results.index(before: results.endIndex)
                lastValue = value
            }
        }
        return results
    } 
}
```

Comment: Good answer . I will use Leo's answer as it solved my problem immediately. Thank you.